# Citrus HTTP custom message using header elements

Tags: citrus-framework

[Click this link to see Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sRbM.png) I want to send a custom string through header elements Send endpoint.

element name="CustomSting" value="Mycustomessage"

And I need to validate the custom string while in receiving endpoint.

element name="CustomSting" value="Mycustomessage"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqtp1.png)

```html
<template name="REST_Connect_Uri">
    <send endpoint="echoEndpoint">
        <message name="helloMessage">
        <data>Template GET message</data>
        </message>
        <header>
      <element name="citrus_endpoint_uri" value="${Rest_EndPoint_URI}"/>
      <element name="citrus_http_method" value="${Rest_Http_Method}"/>
     <element name="Content-Type" value="${Rest_Content_Type}"/>

     <element name="CustomSting" value="Mycustommessge"/>
        </header>
    </send>
</template>

<template name="REST_Get_Message">
        <receive endpoint="echoEndpoint">
            <message name="helloMessage">     
                <resource file="file:D:/expectedOutput/${OUTPUT}"/> 
            </message>
            <header>
            <element name="CustomSting" value="Mycustommessge"/>
            </header>
        </receive>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you please help with this @Christoph Deppisch

Comment: What is the error that you are experiencing with this setup?

Comment: This is the error I am experiencing Caused by :com.consol.citrus.exceptions.ValidationException: Validation failed: Header element 'CustomSting' is missing

Comment: I want to send a value using HTTP headers and validate that particular while receiving

Comment: (hit the above anchor tag in description <Click this link to see Error Message> . I have updated an error picture)

Comment: @Christoph Deppisch

Comment: must be something with your echoEndpoint settings. What kind of endpoint is it? How do you use the templates in a test?